# Como montar esse efeito com JS?

Tags: javascript, loop

Tenho uma lista, e gostaria de criar um loop passando cada um desses elementos, basicamente o que quero é esse efeito:

```
$.each($('.elemento'), function(i, el){
   $(el).fadeIn(100);
   $(el).delay(400).addClass("esconder");
   /*esperar 400ms até o loop rodar de novo fazendo o mesmo efeito com o próximo elemento*/   
});
```

Como eu posso acrescentar esse delay ao fim do meu loop antes que ele interaja com o próximo elemento? Ele passa mostra o elemento e em seguida cria um efeito `fadeOut` já definido no `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer isso seria usando setTimeout ou setInterval.
Acho que algo mais ou menos assim talvez funcione:

```
var elms = $('.elemento');
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (i >= elms.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
        var el = elms[i++];
        $(el).fadeIn(100);
        $(el).delay(400).addClass("esconder");
    }
}, 900);
```

Comment: É possível que tenha uma forma mais "jquery" de resolver isso, usando o método delay ou algo parecido.